# Google Client API and Gradle, com.google.api package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, gradle, google-api-java-client

This is my first time here on StackOverflow, therefore please forgive any possible mistake or lack of details when presenting my issue.
I am trying to make a very simple book database manager for personal use, as I have plenty of books I'd like to catalog. In order for me to avoid writing hundreds of times the name of the book, their authors, upload a nice thumbnail ecc. I figured out that I could use Google Books API to simplify my job. The issue arises when trying to implement Google API, as I can't figure out how to make it work on my application.
I am trying to develop a simple Gradle application coded in Java, using nothing more than Visual Studio Code and Command Line compilation. Should be useful, I'll mention that I am running it from a Fedora Linux machine.
This is my very simple and basic App, configured just to show you the issue that I am encountering:

```
package BookButler;

import com.google.api.*;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Followed by the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.35.2'
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-books', version: 'v1-rev20201021-1.32.1'

}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'BookButler.App'
}
```

The issue is very simple, it generates a compile error because it can't find the com.google.api package.

```
> Task :app:compileJava FAILED
/home/USER/Documents/Applications/BookButler/app/src/main/java/BookButler/App.java:6: error: package com.google.api does not exist
import com.google.api.*;
^
1 error
```

This is driving me nuts, as I'm doing everything as explained on the official guides... Am I missing something?
Thank you all for your precious help!
Cheers

**EDIT:** I have figured some new things out. Running `./gradlew dependencies` shows that I have no current dependencies included for my project, despite having them clearly declared within build.gradle.
Perhaps I have forgotten to perform a particular task to resolve this issue?

Comment: Add `google()`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried adding `google()` to the repositories, but that did not work at all